# One XSLT / Two XML as source

Tags: xml, xslt

First XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
<status>
<code>0</code>
</status>
<newsList>
<news>

<id>1</id>
<title>some</title>
<date>30.11.2011T00:00.00</date>
<shortText>some short text</shortText>
<important>LOW</important>

</news>
```

Second XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
<status>
<code>0</code>
</status>
<newsList>
<news>

<id>1</id>
<text>
Some text here
</text>
</news>
```

I'm transforming the XSLT in the browser.

The result should be dysplaing title date and short Text from the first XML and the text from the second XML.

Any clue how can I do it in the XSLT. I'm thinking of using the document.

Below the XSLT I got so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<h2>News list</h2>
<table border="1">

<xsl:for-each select="newsList/news">
<tr>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="shortText" /></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="date" /></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Finally the script I'm using to load the transform XSLT in HTML in the browser.

```
    <script>
    // the loadXMLDoc function loads the XML and XSL files.
    //It checks what kind of browser the user has and loads the file.

    function loadXMLDoc(dname)
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
      xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {
      xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send(null);
    xhttp.open
    return xhttp.responseXML;
    }


    //The displayResult() function is used to display the XML file styled by the XSL file.


    function displayNewsOverview(xm_l,xs_l)
    {
    // Load XML and XSL file
    xml=loadXMLDoc(xm_l +".xml");
    xsl=loadXMLDoc(xs_l +".xsl");
    //Test what kind of browser the user has
    // If the user has a browser supporting the ActiveX object (IE)
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
      {
    // Use the transformNode() method to apply the XSL style sheet to the xml document
    // Set the body of the current document (id="news-overview") to contain the styled  xml document

      ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
      document.getElementById("news-overview").innerHTML=ex;
      }
    // If the user has a browser that does not support the ActiveX object
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
      {
    // Create a new XSLTProcessor object and import the XSL file to it
      xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
      xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);

    // Use the transformToFragment() method to apply the XSL style sheet to the xml document
      resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);

    // Set the body of the current document (id="example") to contain the styled xml document
        document.getElementById("news-overview").appendChild(resultDocument);
      }
    }

    function displayNewsDetails(xm_l,xs_l)
    {
    document.getElementById("news-overview").innerHTML="";

    // Load XML and XSL file
    xml=loadXMLDoc(xm_l +".xml");
    xsl=loadXMLDoc(xs_l +".xsl");

    //Test what kind of browser the user has
    // If the user has a browser supporting the ActiveX object (IE)
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
      {
    // Use the transformNode() method to apply the XSL style sheet to the xml document
    // Set the body of the current document (id="news-overview") to contain the styled xml document

      ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
      document.getElementById("news-overview").innerHTML=ex;
      }
    // If the user has a browser that does not support the ActiveX object
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
      {
    // Create a new XSLTProcessor object and import the XSL file to it
      xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
      xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);

    // Use the transformToFragment() method to apply the XSL style sheet to the xml document
      resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);

    // Set the body of the current document (id="example") to contain the styled xml document
        document.getElementById("news-overview").appendChild(resultDocument);
      }
    }
    </script>
    </head>


 onLoad="displayNewsOverview('news-overview', 'news-overview')">
```

Any help will be really appreaciated. It's for a job.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the document() function - http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp in your xslt. You can try to add `< ?xml-stylesheet href="nameofxslt" type= "text/xsl" >` to one of your xmls and use the document function to access the other's xml content. By adding the xml directive ( `<?xml-stylesheet` ) you would not need the apply the transform in javascript.

Comment: Do I need to add the xslt href  to the xml in order to use the document?

Comment: If you use your javascript code to transform the xml, you dont need. If you try to load the xml in the browser directly without any transformation code you need to add the "xslt href".